# Jquery add element if not found in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Using jQuery, I am trying to check if a value `x` exists in my array.
Basically, when clicking the `testButton` I have a var `x` that starts from zero Using this value I am trying to check if in the array there is an element with value `0`. If there is, increment `x` and perform the array scan again. This should happen until `x` has a value which is not found in the array. Then at this point I know that I can use this id for the element.
At the moment I have this code that checks if value `x` is in array, but this happens only for the length of the array.
Next iteration should be: `x=3`, x is not in array so can be used as id.
Can someone help to implement this. Thanks

```
  var array = ["0","1","2"];
  var x = 0;

  $("#testButton").click(function(){
        $.each(array, function(index,value){
            if($.inArray(x.toString(),array == -1)){
              console.log('found item with x value in array, increment x and scan the array again');
            }
            else{
              console.log('not in array, add id to element and push current x value to array.');
            }
            x=x+1;
        });
      });
```

Comment: work use of `inArray`
should be
`if($.inArray(x.toString(),array) >= 0){`

Comment: Note use care with the `["0","1","2"];` vs a possible use of `[0,1,2];`

Comment: Thanks. A bit off topic, how to check for [0,1,2].  In array performs check on strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = ["0","1","2"];
a.includes("2"); // true 
a.includes("4"); // false
```

copied from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ["0","1","2"];
var x = 0;

$("#testButton").click(function(){
  while(array.includes(x.toString())) x++;
});
```